# Why is the last character "?" in this string function

Tags: c

I have the following string function:

```
char * to_upper(const char * str) {

    char * upper = malloc(strlen(str)+1);   
    int i;

    for (i=0; str[i] != 0; i++)
        upper[i] = toupper(str[i]);

    upper[i+1] = '\0';

    return upper;

}
```

However, when I call it, it adds a `"?"` to the end (probably an invalid character). If I change the last line, from `upper[i+1] = '\0'` to `upper[i] = '\0'`, it works as expected. What is wrong then with code above?

Additionally, is this the right way to allocate for the string?

```
char * upper = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
```

Or should I instead do:

```
char upper[strlen(str)+1];
```

**Update**: my error above is because length starts at 1, index starts at 0. How should I initialize the string though?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the answer, accoridng to comments:

```
char * to_upper(const char * str) {

  char* upper = malloc(strlen(str));   
  int i;

  for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
      upper[i] = toupper(str[i]);

  upper[i] = '\0';

  return upper;
}
```

With the comments i saw the error in my and your logic. The null string is already there, hence we fall out of the for at `str[i] == '\0'`. So we know `i` is the index we need to set as `\0` in `upper`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Why do you do the cast operation on `char* upper = (char*) malloc(strlen(str)+1); `, what does that do exactly?

Comment: @Shared malloc returns ``void*`` which can't cast to ``char*`` automatically. Or at least it couldn't here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: This answer is wrong. The loop in the original code properly terminates when `str[i]` is a null character. The error is that `upper[i+1] = '\0';` puts the terminating null character in the wrong place, one beyond where it needs to be, and that error remains in the code in this answer.

Comment: @Sens: Your link is for compiling in C++. In C, `void *` may be implicitly converted to other object pointer types, and casts should be avoided to prevent hiding of certain warnings.

Comment: Thank you @Eric Postpischil. I hope the fixes i apllied to my answer are correct and it is good niw.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, you just need to remove the `+1` as you found out. The for loop ends when `str[i]` is equal to `'\0'`, so it makes sense that `upper[i]` should then be set to `'\0'` as well.

Your string initialization is fine.